# why I can't chain square braces after slice method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, slice

I'm curios to know why on the snippet below return "Mango" rather than "M":

```
 var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Lemon", "Apple", "Mango"];
 var myBest = fruits.slice(-1)[0]
 console.log(myBest) // "Mango"
```

normally chaining square braces after string will dealing with it like an array :

```
var myBest = "Mango"[0]
console.log(myBest) // "M"
```

Comment: Where is the `splice` you're using?

Comment: it's a typo ... sorry I'll fix it

Comment: Own effort, please... Read the docs for what slice/splice (whichever you mean now) returns, see the related result without the `[0]` and try to understand why, according to the return described in the docs, then think about what `[0]` at the end does...

Answer (score 0):

`fruits` is an array, and `fruits.slice(-1)` calls [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#Return_value) on the array `fruits`, and that call returns an array (`["Mango"]`) and not a string.

Answer (score 0):

The `Array.prototype.slice()` returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object. In your case you have passed a negative one to it so it returns one element from the end of the old array in the new array object.

As it is a array,you are extracting what is at the 0th index. The 0th index in your case has the last element `'Mango'` from the old array and not a string.

```js
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Lemon", "Apple", "Mango"];
var myBest = fruits.slice(-1); 
console.log(myBest) // Is an array
console.log(myBest[0]) // "Mango"
```